# Проблема с вызовом интерфейса во фрагменте

Tags: android, callback

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема? Есть MainActivity в которой я запускаю Fragment. Во фрагменте я имплементирую InterfaceName. Есть и другая "MainActivity2" активность которая имплементирует тот же интерфейс.

Инициализация в конструкторе анонимного класса: `interfaceName = (InterfaceName) activity;`

При обращении MainActivity2 к данному анонимному классу, обратный вызов срабатывает на все 100%. А вот при вызове со фрагмента - апликашка крашится.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      Process: com.example.admin.myapplication, PID: 12430
      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.admin.myapplication.ads.my_ads.AddTopResult
      at com.example.admin.myapplication.ads.my_ads.AdsAddToTop.<init>(AdsAddToTop.java:41)
      at com.example.admin.myapplication.categories.Categories.onContextItemSelected(Categories.java:173)
      at android.app.Fragment.performContextItemSelected(Fragment.java:2437)
      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2108)
      at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchContextItemSelected(FragmentController.java:304)
      at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3249)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:360)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:194)
     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
     at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:110)
     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:5811)
     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:801)
     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:954)
     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:944)
     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:172)
     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1231)
     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:346)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1577)
     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3970)
     at android.widget.AbsListView$7.run(AbsListView.java:6065)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7409)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

В активности обращаюсь к анонимному классу так:
`new AnonClass(this, id).execute();`

Во фрагменте так:
`new AnonClass(getActivity(), id).execute();`

Слушатель: `interfaceName.interfaceMethodSuccess();`

Если закомментировать `interfaceName = (InterfaceName) activity`, то скрипт успешно продолжает свою работу а так же выводит те же Toast(activity, ...) уведомления и т.д. и т.п. Подскажите, куда копать?

Comment: Покажите всю строку `com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.example.....` и строку с определением класса `MainActivity`.

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос. Вы про какую строку определения говорите? MainActivity у меня по сути только оболочка которая запускает только фрагмент

Comment: Про `public class MainActivity ...`

Comment: Чтобы скастить объект к интерфейсу, необходимо чтобы класс объекта имплементировал этот интерфейс.

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: Всё просто - чтобы использовать `MainActivity` как `InterfaceName` нужно, чтобы `MainActivity` реализовывала этот интерфейс, т.е. в объявлении должно быть `MainActivity implements InterfaceName`

Comment: Ага....мысль я уяснил. Но как тогда быть со фрагментом? Мне его нужно реализовать именно там)

Comment: Сформулируйте то, что Вы пытаетесь реализовать.

Comment: Во фрагменте у меня ListView и Adapter. Интерфейс мне помогает узнать, выполнилась ли какая у меня операция или нет

Comment: `new AnonClass(getActivity(), id).execute();` вы передаёте туда активити (`MainActivity`), которая не реализует нужный интерфейс. Передавайте вместо `getActivity()` ваш фрагмент. Если не получится реализовать, добавьте в вопрос код класса `AnnonClass`.

Comment: Мне  самое главное было понять мои ошибки, я их понял, пошёл разбираться. Спасибо) Оформите пожалуйста ответ, я отмечу его как верный)